# Is it possible the debugger runs twice in the same time?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2017

Lets say im using a timer , which cause a series of actions every 0.001seconds.
Does the debugger knows how to run in 2 differents lines in my code in the same time?

Answer (score 0):

The debugger can manage it. But if you use step by step debug (F10), it can lead to something chaotic going from a thread to another.

Comment: I mean, I just used the step-by-step debug, and it was like every even step was on one route of lines, and every odd step was on other route of lines.